# Change a column value based on nchar

Tags: r, function, dimension

I have the following issue: Consider a dataframe of equal length with the columns title and subtitle. title is rather clean data and subtitle is rather messy (wrong values, NAs, ...) However, when subtitle is filled in correctly, it contains a lot more information than my title variable.

I would like to replace the values in my title column where the nchar of a certain subtitle observation exceeds the nchar of the title observation.

at the moment my failed code looks like this:

```
    #filter from real table
    baseTable_sentiment <- filter(baseTable, theme_ecoFin == 1) 
    #with this code I try to do what I explained, while coping with the NA's in subtitle
    baseTable_sentiment$title <- baseTable_sentiment$subtitle[nchar(baseTable_sentiment$subtitle , allowNA = TRUE , keepNA = TRUE) > nchar(baseTable_sentiment$title) , ]
```

an alternative approach to cope with the NAs

```
 #filter from real table
    baseTable_sentiment <- filter(baseTable, theme_ecoFin == 1)
    #change NA to text value "na"
    baseTable_sentiment$subtitle <- replace(baseTable_sentiment$subtitle,which(is.na(baseTable_sentiment$subtitle)),"na")
    #same code as before
    baseTable_sentiment$title <- baseTable_sentiment$subtitle[nchar(baseTable_sentiment$subtitle ) > nchar(baseTable_sentiment$title) , ]
```

Now when I run one of the two examples: I get the following error:

> Error in
>   baseTable_sentiment$subtitle[(nchar(baseTable_sentiment$subtitle,  :
>   incorrect number of dimensions

However: when i check all used dimensions

```
> > > length(baseTable_sentiment$subtitle)  [1] 170206
> > > length(baseTable_sentiment$title)  [1] 170206
> > > length(nchar(baseTable_sentiment$subtitle , allowNA = TRUE ) > nchar(baseTable_sentiment$title))  [1] 170206
```

How can I fix this, or do you guys have an alternative way to do this operation?

The following link contains a [data example](http://we.tl/GmNc9Ab8vQ)

Thank you in advance

Olivier

Comment: what's in `baseTable` ?

Comment: The baseTable contains meta data about newscoverage and filter variables such as theme_ecofin (economic and financial themed news) The baseTable does'nt contain any NA values expect for the subtitle variable. It contains different data-types, but i assure you that subtitle and title are both of type "character" (I just controlled it to be sure)

Comment: please share an example dataset that reproduces your problem.

Comment: I uploaded a tiny part (20 observations) of the baseTable_sentiment: http://we.tl/GmNc9Ab8vQ

Comment: Please share the data in your post. Nobody will want to download unknown files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the error: the dimension of my title does not correspond anymore with the new dimension created by the condition after the assignment.

```
baseTable_sentiment$title[nchar(baseTable_sentiment$subtitle , allowNA = TRUE , keepNA = FALSE) > nchar(baseTable_sentiment$title) ]<- baseTable_sentiment$subtitle[nchar(baseTable_sentiment$subtitle , allowNA = TRUE , keepNA = FALSE) > nchar(baseTable_sentiment$title)  ]
```

The dimensions are now matched and the code runs perfectly